# Read regex from properties file in java

Tags: java, regex, properties

I have problem reading values like `(\+?\s*[0-9]+\s*)+` from properties file in java, because the value , what I get with `getProperty()` method is `(+?s*[0-9]+s*)+`.

Escaping of values in properties file is not an option yet.

Any ideas?

Comment: Not an option _yet_? What do you mean?

Comment: ... is not an option `yet`!

Comment: if nothing else works than it will be an option.

Comment: Backslash has special meaning in a properties file. For example, it allows an entry to continue on the next line. It is impossible to work around this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just read using a classical `BufferedReader` instead:

```
final URL url = MyClass.class.getResource("/path/to/propertyfile");
// check if URL is null;

String line;

try (
    final InputStream in = url.openStream();
    final InputStreamReader r 
        = new InputStreamReader(in, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    final BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(r);
) {
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
        // process line
}
```

Adapt to Java 6 if necessary...

Comment: it works, but where's the sense in this?  If you decide to use properties files for this, then why write them in way that will make them invalid?  If you decide to do something custom, don't call them properties files but something else.  Just escape the backslashes...

Comment: @JoeriHendrickx meh, don't ask _me_ :p

Answer (score 3):

I am pretty late to answer this question, but maybe this could help others that end up here.

Newer versions of Java (not sure which, I am using 8) support escaping of values by using `\\` to represent the normal `\` we are used to.

For example, in your case, `(\\+?\\s*[0-9]+\\s*)+` is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I think this class could be solution for the backslash problem in properties file.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class ProperProps {

    HashMap<String, String> Values = new HashMap<String, String>();

    public ProperProps() {
    };

    public ProperProps(String filePath) throws java.io.IOException {
        load(filePath);
    }

    public void load(String filePath) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath));
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            if (line.trim().length() == 0 || line.startsWith("#"))
                continue;

            String key = line.replaceFirst("([^=]+)=(.*)", "$1");
            String val = line.replaceFirst("([^=]+)=(.*)", "$2");
            Values.put(key, val);

        }
        reader.close();
    }


    public String getProperty(String key) {
        return Values.get(key);
    }


    public void printAll() {
        for (String key : Values.keySet())
            System.out.println(key +"=" + Values.get(key));
    }


    public static void main(String [] aa) throws IOException {
        // example & test 
        String ptp_fil_nam = "my.prop";
        ProperProps pp = new ProperProps(ptp_fil_nam);
        pp.printAll();
    }
}
```